# Related to spring boot resttemplate when i am calling an api and it is throwing an error, I am unable to catch that in rest template

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In the rest template, I am calling an API and an error is occurring (mono exception)there I had caught the exception and thrown the same exception from there, in the rest template I am getting `httpserverexception` rather than the exception that I had thrown. I need the exception which is coming from the API, how to find the exception which is coming from the api 
 Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is there any code that you can put in question ? Unless that's provided this question might be closed, Please edit question with minimal data required..

Comment: How did the REST API return the exception? It might not return anything useful, other than a general HTTP status 500 (Internal Error) with generic payload just saying "error occurred". You cannot turn that into a specific exception on the client, if the server doesn't give you the needed information, so without knowing what the server returns, it's impossible to know whether you can even do what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The exception you throwed in the other server will have to send a response with the exception on it's body, and you'll have to get the raw body from the `RestClientResponseException`.

All the exceptions throwed by a `RestTemplate` call are subclasses from the `HttpClientErrorException` (if 4xx happen) or `HttpServerErrorException` (if 5xx happen), thus these two are subclasses from `HttpStatusCodeException` (which is a subclass of `RestClientResponseException`)

I do not suggest it, but you can generalize and handle both of them as a `HttpStatusCodeException`.

The reason I do not suggest it, is because you may want to have a different handling based on client error or server error.

These two examples should work:

**Catching as `HttpStatusCodeException`** (generalizing)

```
try {
    restTemplate.exchange(...); // do your request (can use get, post, etc..)
} catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
    log.info("Error occurred: {}", e.getResponseBodyAsString());
}
```

**Catching as `HttpClientErrorException` and `HttpServerErrorException`**

```
try {
    restTemplate.exchange(...); // do your request (can use get, post, etc..)
} catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
    log.info("OH NO! IT'S AN ERROR FROM THE CLIENT: {}", e.getResponseBodyAsString());
} catch (HttpServerErrorException e) {
    log.info("OH NO! IT'S AN ERROR FROM THE SERVER: {}", e.getResponseBodyAsString());
}
```